# How to feed report from data input into form?

Tags: ms-access

Ok so here is what I'm trying to do. I have a form in which the user inputs a bunch of information, then once they are done and click view report, I want it to populate into a report in which they can then print.

So far I have tried to set the report text boxes' control source to:

`Forms![frmMyFormName]![txtMyTextBox]`  (using generic names here)

This hasn't worked, and I am having trouble finding how to do this. None of the data being input into the form is on a table or in a query. I want it to be input in the form, then to after the event to populate in the report. The form and the report have the same formatting, with the same names for all the text boxes. I feel like this is an easy fix, I just cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try with: `=Forms![frmMyFormName]![txtMyTextBox] `.

Comment: Why not saving data to table?

Comment: I don't want to save the data to a table because this form/report will be constantly changing. Every time the form/report is updated, all of the information will be different from the data that would then be on the table. I dont think there is a real need for it to even be in a table.

Comment: @Gustav  
I tried that, still gives me the  #NAME? on the report where that is the control source

Comment: what language of MS Access are you using? Is it another language than English?

Comment: You can also try using the Expression Builder, it's the button with the three dots in the Control Source of the text box on the report, to build the expression.

Comment: @jbud I have tried to use the expression builder (you are referring to the three dots in the control source menu right?) and built the expression that way, but that gives me the #NAME? error.

Also to answer your other question, everything is in English.

Comment: please check if you have any broken references in your VBA code window

Comment: make sure all your code compiles and do a compact and repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bound form to a table.

Then to launch/display the report, do this;

```
if me.Dirty = True then me.Dirty = false
docmd.OpenReport "MyReport",,,"ID = " & me!id
```

So two lines of code. The simple trick/matter is to use a form bound to a table, and thus as per above you use/pick up the PK, and launch the report to the one current forms record. And that means the report can be (should be) based on that SAME table as the form. And thus once again, you don't need any code or anything special for that report - just designer it, and yo are done.